# Не обновляется ListView после подгрузки

Tags: java, android

Подскажите не работает добавление в `ListView`. Запрос работает, а список не обновляется.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages_all_news, container, false);
    NewsList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.AllNewsList);

    try {
        String type = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            messages = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(savedInstanceState));
        } else {
            bundle = getArguments();
            if (bundle != null) {
                messages = new JSONObject(bundle.getString("messages"));
                type = bundle.getString("type");
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0 ; j < messages.getJSONObject("messages").getJSONArray("list").length() ; j++){
            arrayAdapter.add(String.valueOf(messages.getJSONObject("messages").getJSONArray("list").getJSONObject(j)));
        }

        messagesAdapters = new MessagesAdapters(v.getContext(), arrayAdapter);
        NewsList.setAdapter(messagesAdapters);

        NewsList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            private int currentVisibleItemCount;
            private int currentScrollState;
            private int currentFirstVisibleItem;
            private int totalItem;


            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
                this.isScrollCompleted();
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                 int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
                this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
                this.totalItem = totalItemCount;
            }

            private void isScrollCompleted() {
                if (totalItem - currentFirstVisibleItem == currentVisibleItemCount
                        && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    onUpdateList();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return v;
}

public void onUpdateList(){
    try {
        int page = Integer.valueOf(messages.getJSONObject("messages").getString("page"));
        int total = Integer.valueOf(messages.getJSONObject("messages").getString("total")) + 1;

        if(total > page){
            Map<String, String> paramsApi = new HashMap<>();
            paramsApi.put("oid", String.valueOf(Constants.ID_OPERATOR));
            paramsApi.put("type", bundle.getString("type"));
            paramsApi.put("page", String.valueOf(page++));

            getAllMessages news = new getAllMessages(getContext(), paramsApi, new getAllMessages.MessagesCallback(){

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JSONObject result) {
                    try {
                        for (int j = 0 ; j < result.getJSONObject("messages").getJSONArray("list").length() ; j++){
                            arrayAdapter.add(String.valueOf(result.getJSONObject("messages").getJSONArray("list").getJSONObject(j)));
                        }
                        messagesAdapters.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            news.execute();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Как связан `arrayAdapter`, в который Вы добавляете данные с `messagesAdapters`, который является адаптером для `ListView`?

Comment: @post_zeew messagesAdapters = new MessagesAdapters(v.getContext(), arrayAdapter);

Comment: Отображаются ли какие-то данные до подзагрузки новых данных? Также проверьте размер массива `arrayAdapter` до и после подгрузки. Может быть новых данных просто нет.

Comment: @post_zeew похоже `arrayAdapter` это просто лист с очень странным названием =)